# gdal_grid failing to set nodata

Tags: gdal

Using gdal_grid for spatial interpolation I have run across a problem: the nodata argument is ignored. The only solution I have found for this is to then use `gdal_translate` but it is rather cumbersome (see below). My bash scripting skills are very, very minimal. Can anyone suggest an improvement, like passing the outputted file directly to the next tool?

```
gdal_grid -zfield "D2012" \
-a invdist:power=2.0:smoothing=0.0:radius1=0.0:radius2=0.0:angle=0.0:max_points=0:min_points=0:nodata=-9999 \
-txe 647822 651672 -tye 7535500 7537800 -outsize 77 46 \
-of GTiff -ot Float64 -l probe2004_2012 probe2004_2012.shp ./Output/temp.tiff
gdal_translate -stats -a_nodata -9999 -a_srs EPSG:3006 ./Output/temp.tiff ./Output/2012_IDW_2_50.tiff
rm ./Output/temp.tiff
```

Comment: The problem still exists(5th Dec 2013, gdal 1.10.1), nodata values are set to -9999 but the metadata for the file doesn't reflect this so that the -9999 values are treated as data.

Comment: They might be thinking of this as a default value to store in the array, while identifying that value as flag for nodata value is a separate function.  That said, one would think that this might work: ######################## gdal_grid -co PROFILE=GDALGeoTIFF -co TIFFTAG_GDAL_NODATA=-9999 .... #############  but with gdal  11.1 it fails with "Warning 6: Driver GTiff does not support TIFFTAG_GDAL_NODATA creation option"

Answer (score 2):

I use a short Python function that sets the nodata value of an existing grid and so far this works well for me. I use it from within Python scripts but it could of course be wrapped into a stand-alone utility that accepts command-line arguments.

```
def setNodata(fPath, nodata):
  dataSet = gdal.Open(fPath, gdal.GA_Update)
  band = dataSet.GetRasterBand(1)
  band.SetNoDataValue(float(nodata))
```

Answer (score 1):

As in your comment, the nodata=9999 values are used by the algorithm to set the values at the pixels, but the output file's nodata attribute is not set to identify these pixels as no-data pixels.

I posted a bug report at http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5605 and it looks like rouault fixed it with http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/27565.  Until you have an updated gdal_grid executable, you can use the workaround:

```
gdal_translate -a_nodata -9999 temp.tiff final.tiff
```